# How to keep WSGI from launching multiple instances

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I have a python web application that I have configured in apache as:

WSGIScriptAlias   /firetalk   /scripts/firetalkServer2

When I access this from javascript using XMLHttpRequest, WSGI/Apache end up launching multiple instances which breaks what I am trying to accomplish.

So, is there any way to limit WSGI/Apache to a single instance of the specified python script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put the WSGI app in daemon mode and tell it to use a single process. Note that this could have a detrimental effect on performance.

Comment: Use of daemon mode doesn't automatically imply worse performance.

Comment: I agree. But if you get stuck running large chunks of Python code while the server is getting hammered then some of the requests will have to wait.

Comment: It is actually a lot more complicated than that and some work is being done in mod_wsgi 4.0 to address some shortcomings when things slow down in a severe way in order to avoid backlogging.

Comment: Graham - I have this firetalk process running in the same virtual host as my django application which also utilizes WSGI.  How would I specify a single firetalk but multiple dango processes? @graham

Answer (score 1):

This is more in answer to qualification on what is desired in comment to other answer.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess firetalk # Uses default of single process and 15 threads.
WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=5 threads=3

WSGIScriptAlias /firetalk /scripts/firetalkServer2 \
    process-group=firetalk application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias / /scripts/djangoServer \
    process-group=django application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

The firetalk application will go to single process with 15 threads.

The Django application will go to multiples processes.

Requires mod_wsgi 3.0 or later as using process-group/application-group options to WSGIScriptAlias. Use of options does mean WSGI script preloaded on process startup.

Alternatively could do:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess firetalk # Uses default of single process and 15 threads.
WSGIDaemonProcess other processes=5 threads=3

WSGIScriptAlias /firetalk /scripts/firetalkServer2

<Location /firetalk>
WSGIProcessGroup firetalk
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>

WSGIScriptAlias / /scripts/djangoServer

WSGIProcessGroup other
```

The firetalk application will go to single process with 15 threads.

Other applications get distributed across multiple process each in distinct sub interpreter of those processes.

WSGI scripts lazily loaded on first request.